# Detected devices name

Tags: sd-card, dev

I am using the [Barebox](http://www.barebox.org/) bootloader to boot into an embedded system.

I am wondering why some SD-card of mine shows up as 2 devices

/dev/disk0.0 
/dev/disk0

And sometimes another SD card it shows only as 1 device

/dev/disk0

?

Comment: You have not advised your OS / distro, but my guess is that it depends on the partitioning - as cards can be partitioned like hard drives.

Comment: Sorry. my distro is barebox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the first sd card is partitioned. /dev/disk0 is your sd card and /dev/disk0.0 would be one of the partitions on that card. You can analyze the partitioning scheme further using your favorite partitioning program, popular ones are fdisk for terminal and gparted for gui.